# Correlation between subscales

Tags: correlation, likert, scales, cronbachs-alpha

I have used a scale, which includes 3 subscales. Given that the 3 subscales make part of the same,validated instrument, what conclusions can be drawn from the fact that a pair of subscales intercorrelate strongly?